# When hashing an API key, should I hash the suffix / prefix as well?

Tags: security, database-design, hash, authorization, api-key

I am generating API key similarly to Stripe where my key is {prefix}_{guid}_{suffix}.

- Prefix is a constant
- Guid is the "password" portion of the key
- Suffix is a random 4 character string that will be visible to the user

Should the entire string {prefix}_{guid}_{suffix} be hashed or only {guid}? If only the guid should be hashed, is there any security concern with storing the suffix next to the hash in the database?

I've read through a few blogs but haven't found much that touches on this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a random prefix and/or suffix to a value before hashing is called [salting](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/). It is a recommended practice.

The purpose is to prevent someone from knowing whether, for example, UserA has the same password as UserB, because their hashed values are identical. Hence, you add a cryptographically secure random value prefix/suffix (salt) for each user, then even if they use the same password, their hashed values would always be different.

But in your case, if you already provide a [version 4 GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) as a pre-hashed value, it's guaranteed to be unique, so you don't have to add a salt.